# How to add billing permission to expo managed app?

Tags: expo, in-app-purchase, android-permissions

I’m using expo sdk 42.0.0

The relevant platform is android

I’m using expo managed workflow, and right now I’m trying to implement IAP (In App Purchases). I saw that google play won’t let me add In App Product because I don’t have the BILLING permission in my apk/aab.

What I already did:

- I’ve installed expo-in-app-purchases because I though it would make expo add the BILLING permission automatically.
- I tried added to the app.json file the following line: `"permissions": ["com.android.vending.BILLING"]`
- I also notice that when I add other permissions, it does not work. Maybe there is a problem with expo app.json permission in android.

Nothing worked. What can I do more to add the BILLING permission to my app?

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

To implement IAP u need one special package, u can find the tutorial here in the doc:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/

Comment: The question already stated that they installed the package as outlined in the docs, also if the page goes missing in the future this link would lead to nothing.

Answer (score -3):

Expo announced that it's their bug and how to workaround it. [The link](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/607#issuecomment-918076521)

Comment: The link is incorrect, doesn't mention anything about adding Billing permissions or anything remotely related?